# Access to remote docker swarm/k8s clusters

Tags: docker, docker-compose, swarm

How to access to remote server `Docker Swarm` from my local computer with OS Windows.

Remote Docker Swarm cluster with manager pc name `mss-swarm.test.local (172.12.20.61)`.
Docker Desktop ver 20.10.16.

Now on **local** PC (Docker Client) run:

```
 #docker -H tcp://mss-swarm.test.local:2375 version 

error during connect: Get "http://mss-swarm.test.local:2375/v1.24/version": dial tcp 172.12.20.61:2375: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.25
 Version:           20.10.16
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.10
 Git commit:        aa7e414
 Built:             Thu May 12 09:17:07 2022
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true*
```

or----

```
 #docker -H tcp://172.12.20.61:2375 version
error during connect: Get "http://172.12.20.61:2375/v1.24/version":
dial tcp 172.12.20.61:2375: connectex: No connection could be made
because the target machine actively refused it. Client:  Cloud
integration: v1.0.25  Version:           20.10.16  API version:      
1.41  Go version:        go1.17.10  Git commit:        aa7e414  Built:             Thu May 12 09:17:07 2022  OS/Arch:           windows/amd64  Context:  
default  Experimental:      true*
```

Added the variable `env:DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.12.20.61:2375` does not solve the problem.

Added via `docker context create` also does not work.

Added in `daemon.json` (C:\ProgramData\Docker\config) on remote Docker Swarm also does not work.

```
 "hosts": [ 
 "npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine_windows" , "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"    ]
```

My goal, get access to remote server from local docker CLI to manage cluster. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're not absolutely 100% sure you can set up remote Docker socket access securely, do not try to enable it.  Allowing unencrypted remote access to the Docker socket is a very easy way to get your host compromised; Google "Docker cryptojacking" for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation there was the problem of closing the ports by security. After opening the ports, the settings were made and everything is available.